# How to connect to an external database using JDBC in ServiceNow

Tags: jdbc

I need to connect to an external database using JDBC in ServiceNow. For me the external database is being connected by VHI. The link below provides way of connection using JDBC
(https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/verastream-host-integrator/7-9/design-tool/connectors-apis/jdbc-connector.html)

Could you please tell how to connect to a VHI system using JDBC in ServiceNow?